# Finding norm of a bounded linear operator defined on a Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

**Question:** Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and $\dim(H)>1$. Let $\{v_1,v_2\}\subset H$ be an orthogonal set of nonzero vectors. Suppose that for all $x\in H$,
$$ Tx=\langle x,v_1\rangle v_2+\langle x,v_2\rangle v_1.$$
Prove that $T$ is bounded linear operator and compute the norm of the operator $T$.

I could prove that, $T$ is bounded through proving this, for all $x\in H$,
$$\|Tx\|\leq 2\|v_1\|\|v_2\|\|x\|.$$
Thus, $\|T\|\leq 2\|v_1\|\|v_2\|$.
Next, using orthogonality of $v_1,v_2$, I could show that, $\|T(\dfrac{v_1}{\|v_1\|})\|=\|v_1\|\|v_2\|$, which gives $\|v_1\|\|v_2\|\leq \|T\|$.

But then how to find the norm of $T$? Help please.

Comment: Try to compute $T(v_1+v_2)$

Comment: Yes, I did. It is $\|v_1\|^2v_2+\|v_2\|^2v_1$. But then what?

Comment: @Avisek Sharma May I know where did you find that question? This question has appeared in ISI PhD entrance test this year. Thanks.

Comment: @Anacardium yes you are right. I got it from there too.

Comment: Oh! I see. How was your exam?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set
$$
v_1=\|v_1\|e_1,\,\,v_2=\|v_2\|e_2.
$$
Clearly, $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is an orthonormal set and
$$
Tx=\langle x,v_1\rangle v_2+\langle x,v_2\rangle v_1
=\|v_1\|\|v_2\|\big(\langle x,e_1\rangle e_2+\langle x,e_2\rangle e_1\big),
$$
and hence
$$
\|Tx\|=\|v_1\|\|v_2\|\big(\langle x,e_1\rangle^2+\langle x,e_2\rangle^2\big)^{1/2}\le \|v_1\|\|v_2\| \|x\|,
$$
since
$$
\big(\langle x,e_1\rangle^2+\langle x,e_2\rangle^2\big)^{1/2}\le \|x\|.
$$
Hence $\|T\|\le \|v_1\|\|v_2\|$.

Also
$$
Tv_1=\langle v_1,v_1\rangle v_2=\|v_1\|^2v_2
$$
which implies
$$
\|Tv_1\|=\langle v_1,v_1\rangle v_2=\|v_1\|\|v_2\| \cdot \|v_1\|
$$
and hence $\|T\|\ge \|v_1\|\|v_2\|$.

Altogether $\|T\| = \|v_1\|\|v_2\|$.

Comment: Don't you get $$\left \|Tx \right \| = \left \| v_1 \right \| \left \| v_2 \right \| \left ( {\left \lvert \left \langle x,e_1 \right \rangle \right \rvert}^2 + {\left \lvert \left \langle x,e_2 \right \rangle \right \rvert}^2 \right )^{\frac {1} {2}}\ ?$$ Because $\left \langle \cdot\ ,\ \cdot \right \rangle$ might be a complex inner product. Am I right?

Comment: Also how do you get $$\left ( {\left \lvert \left \langle x,e_1 \right \rangle \right \rvert}^2 + {\left \lvert \left \langle x,e_2 \right \rangle \right \rvert}^2 \right )^{\frac {1} {2}} \leq \left \|x \right \|\ ?$$ Can you please explain? Thanks.

Comment: I think you have applied Parseval's identity here. But for that I need to know whether there exists an orthonormal basis for the underlying Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ containing the set of orthonormal vectors $\{e_1,e_2\}.$ For finite dimensional we can use *basis extension theorem and Gram-Schmidt process of orthogonalization* to obtain a orthonormal basis for the underlying space containing a given orthonormal set. But I am not quite sure whether this result is still valid for infinite dimensional vector spaces or not.

Comment: Actually, I have used Bessel's Inequality, which is related to Parseval's Identity.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $T(av_1+bv_2)=a\|v_1\|^{2}v_2+b\|v_2\|^{2}v_1$ so $\|T(av_1+bv_2)\|^{2}=\|v_1\|^{2}\|v_2\|^{2} (a^{2}\|v_1\|^{2}+b^{2}\|v_2\|^{2})$. The norm of the operator is simply the square root of  the  supremum of $\|v_1\|^{2}\|v_2\|^{2} (a^{2}\|v_1\|^{2}+b^{2}\|v_2\|^{2})$ over all $a,b$ such that $\|av_1+bv_2\|^{2}=a^{2}\|v_1\|^{2}+b^{2}\|v_2\|^{2} \leq 1$. So we get $\|T\|=||v_1||\|v_2\|$.

Comment: Please, elaborate it little bit. I didn't get anything.

Comment: @AvisekSharma I am just applying the definition of $\|T\|$. Take an arbitrary vector $x$ in the space spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$ and compute $\|Tx\|$. Then take the supremum of this over all $x$ such that $\|x\|\leq 1$. That, by definition, is the norm of $T$. [$T$ is zero on the orthogonal complement of this two dimensional subspace so it is enough to find the norm on this subspace].